# find: File system loop detected; '/snap/core18/1144' is part of the same file system loop as '/' Ubuntu Core OS

Tags: ubuntu-core, openssl

`Sudo find / -iname ".demoCA' -type d`  fails with these error messages

```
find: File system loop detected; ‘/snap/core18/1144’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/’.
find: File system loop detected; ‘/writable/system-data/snap/core18/1144’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/’
```

Trying to find openssl default CA folder on ubuntu core 18.
openssl is not a snap

[image]

Comment: The command you provide fails with `Command 'Sudo' not found`.

Comment: it was sudo -s  (mustbe 15 characters in length)

Comment: There is another typo in the command, look at the quoting, it's incorrect. Please provide correct information, best is to copy directly from terminal (command and it's output). You may look into `~/.bash_history` which command you really used.

Comment: `find /  -iname ".demoCA" -type d`  this command from ~/.bash_history

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1176410/edit) your question accordingly. I tried this command already and don't get this error. I suspect you have a strange mount, maybe the `findmnt`-command will give you a clue.

Comment: are you using ubuntu-core the snap distro (no apt, .deb, etc)

Comment: added screenshot

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood your last comment, no, I don't use the ubuntu-core snap. Please update your question with relevant information.

Comment: Trying to find openssl default CA folder on ubuntu core 18, no worries

Answer (score -1, accepted):

incorrect usage (30 characters for post)